# Unity: запуск случайного ауидо

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Мне нужно, чтобы при определенном событии (при отдалении одного объекта от другого) запускался любой из аудиофайлов, содержащихся в массиве:

```
public AudioClip[] Asounds;
```

Пытался выполнить следующим образом:

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Asounds[Random.Range(0, Asounds.Length)]);
```

Данная строка находится в операторе if внутри функции update(). Проблема в том, что все (их 5) аудиофайлов запускаются сразу, а не один случайный.
Если вставить данную строку в функцию start(), всё работает

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего у вас условие срабатывает множество раз (функция Update() вызывается каждый кадр). Добавьте внутрь вашего условия `Debug.Log("test")`, запустите и посмотрите в консоли сколько раз он был вызван. Если вызовов множество, то необходимо ограничить количество вызовов до 1 добавив, например, переменную типа bool. Для примера:

```
bool isCanPlayAudio = true;
void Update()
{
  if(ваше условие)
  {
    if(isCanPlayAudio)
    {
       isCanPlayAudio = false;
       GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Asounds[Random.Range(0, Asounds.Length)]);
    }
  }
}
```

Только для повторного вызова переменную нужно снова перевести в состояние false, к примеру, после того, как завершилось воспроизведение предыдущего аудиофайла.